# Node.js: A new pool getting created every time instead of using the same

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a puppeteer browser pool using module `generic pool`, I am also doing background processing using `bull` where the pool instances are used.

I am seeing that a new pool is getting created all the time, instead of creating once and then referring to it always.

I have set `max` property to 2, but still see that `n` number of browser instances are spun up instead of resuing any resource out of 2 or throwing an error when resource are maxed out.

below is my code

browser-pool.js

```
const genericPool = require('generic-pool');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const browserParams = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? {
  headless: false,
  devtools: false,
  executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
}
:
{
  headless: true,
  devtools: false,
  executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable',
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
};

const factory = {
  create: function() {
    return puppeteer.launch(browserParams);
  },
  destroy: function(instance) {
    console.log('closing browser in hrere.....');
    instance.close();
  }
};

const opts = {
  max: 2
};

const pool =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    resolve(genericPool.createPool(factory, opts));
  } catch(err){
    console.log('in reject error');
    reject(err.message)
  }
});

module.exports = pool;
```

acquire-browser.js

```
const pool = require('./browser-pool');

class AcquireBrowser {
  static async withBrowser(fn) {
   const pP = await pool.then(function(t) {
      return t;
    });

    const browser = await pP.acquire().catch(function(err){
      console.log(err.message);
      console.log('resource max limit reached')
    });

    try {
      await fn(browser);
    } finally {
      console.log('before...');
      console.log(pool);
      pP.release(browser);
      console.log('after...');
      console.log(pool);
    }
  }
}

module.exports =  AcquireBrowser;
```

***process-data.js**

```
const AcquirePool = require('./acquire-pool');

async function performExport(params){

  const resp = await AcquirePool.withBrowser(async function(client){
    //procesing
  });
}
```

Looks like every-time a new connection pool is created instead of having just one.

How do i ensure that a pool is created only once and not for every request.

Any help in this would be really really great. Thanks.